# After attaching a volume to Windows 2016 instance thru AWS mangement console, I can't find it when I remote into the windows server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was able to create a new volume (attached pic). It says successfully attached to the windows 2016 instance. But when I RDP into that windows server, I only see "C" drive but not the newly attached volume. How do I see that ?

[Attached volume from AWS console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETWfT.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server 2016 instances inside EC2 [don't initialize secondary volumes at launch](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secondary-volumes-windows-server-2016/).

According to the link above, running the following command will cause it to do so every time the instance reboots:

`C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeDisks.ps1 –Schedule`

See also: [Configuring a Windows Instance Using EC2Launch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html#ec2launch-mapping)

Comment: on windows 16 instance I launched doesn't have "ProgramData" folder on C drive

Comment: when I created windows 2016 instance, I picked 64 bit OS

Comment: In Windows Explorer, the folder is probably not showing because it's a hidden system folder and not shown by default. You should still be able to navigate there by typing the path in the address bar, or by opening a prompt and changing to the directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks

Answer (score 0):

Step1:
    Open the C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2- 
     Windows\Launch\Config\DriveLetterMappingConfig.json 
file in a text editor.

Step2:
update values: 
      "volumeName": "Volume Name",
      "driveLetter": "D"

Step3:  RUN Below Command
PS C:> C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeDisks.ps1